# How to append to [[String : [String]]] = [[:]] instead of [String : [String]] = [:]?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, arraylist, append

I am getting list of arrays from Firestore database and appending the, to the following variable:

```
var productTags : [String : [String]] = [:]
```

This is my code for getting the data and appending it to the `productTags` variable:

```
db.collection(DatabaseRef.searchTags).document(DatabaseRef.productTags).getDocument { snapshot, error in

            guard error == nil, let snapshot = snapshot else {
                return
            }

            let data = snapshot.data()!


            for (key, _) in data {

                let productTags = data["\(key)"] as? [Any]

                if let maxIndex = productTags?.count {

                    for index in 0..<maxIndex {

                        if let tag = productTags![index] as? String, tag != "" {

                            if self.productTags[key] == nil {
                                self.productTags[key] = []
                                self.productTags[key]?.append(tag)
                            } else {
                                self.productTags[key]?.append(tag)
                            }

                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

This works perfectly fine and gives me the following results:

```
productTags = [ product1 : [tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4],
                product2 : [tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag 5], 
                product3 : [tag1, tag2, tag3]
              ]
```

However, I need to turn the dictionary into an array so the results would look like this:

```
productTags = [ [product1 : [tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4]],
                [product2 : [tag1, tag2, tag3, tag4, tag 5]], 
                [product3 : [tag1, tag2, tag3]]
              ]
```

So my variable would look like this instead:

```
var productTagsArray : [[String : [String]]] = [[:]]
```

How would I change my code so I can append it into an array instead of a dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest converting the dictionary to the array after you are done:

```
let productTagsArray = productTags.map { [$0: $1] }
```

---

Also, you can use the `default` version of dictionary lookup to change this:

```
if self.productTags[key] == nil {
    self.productTags[key] = []
    self.productTags[key]?.append(tag)
} else {
    self.productTags[key]?.append(tag)
}
```

into this:

```
self.productTags[key, default: []].append(tag)
```